# How to define a case sensitive uniqueness index using entity framework core?

Tags: sql, indexing, entity-framework-core, case-sensitive

Currently I define the following in my code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasIndex(p => new
                {
                    p.Name
                }).IsUnique();
```

This results in a sql insertion error when I try to add 'John' when 'john' already exists. How should I define this index if I want to be able to add both 'John' and 'john' (so a case sensitive index)?

Comment: May be you cannot do that from EF Core. but you can do it sql server level.

Comment: I believe that @TanvirArjel is right, you can change the collation of a table, and possibly a single field in SQL Server to make it case-sensitive.